# cant run file with sys.argv

Tags: argv, nameerror, sys

I'm unable to go ahead. please help. 
[this is a link for the code i used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS5P9.png)
i tried downloading the module using cmd windows 10 but that is also showing an error...

C:\Users\kayza\Desktop\image_converter>python jpgtopng.py jpeg png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jpgtopng.py", line 5, in 
    image_input = sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS5P9.png)
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: Hi Kayzad. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please paste code from your Sublime to question. Each row start with 4 spaces, to keep formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you import every module from the package `sys`. Because of that you can't access them with the dot notation (`sys.argv[]`). 
You have two options to fix this.

1. Access the method like this `argv[]` without the `sys.` in front of it.
2. (the cleaner option)
   Change your import statement to `import sys`